# tiling images every nth child + something?

Tags: jquery, loops, css-selectors

I have this code http://underwaterpistol.co.uk/snaps-old.html

I have a random number of images, and what I want to do is, every 1,2,3,4 image put in a div "box", in "big-box" I want every 5th image + "box" then I want img 6+7 to be floating next to it, the again image 8,9,10,11 in "box" and image 12 in "big box" with "box".

I've hard coded it by adding classes to each image and appending them into separate small boxes("box") and then taking the image after (by class name) and sticking it in "big box" along with "box".

My maths absolutely sucks, I think I'm looking to repeat a loop every 7th image.

```
$("<div class='box'></div>").prependTo("body");
    $(".first").appendTo(".box");
    $(".second").appendTo(".box");
    $(".third").appendTo(".box");
    $(".fourth").appendTo(".box");

    $("<div class='box2'></div>").prependTo("body");
    $(".fifth").appendTo(".box2");
    $(".box").prependTo(".box2");

    $("<div class='box3'></div>").appendTo("body");
    $(".eighth").appendTo(".box3");
    $(".ninth").appendTo(".box3");
    $(".tenth").appendTo(".box3");
    $(".eleventh").appendTo(".box3");

    $("<div class='box4'></div>").appendTo("body");
    $(".twelfth").appendTo(".box4");
    $(".box3").prependTo(".box4");
```

and the css

```
img{
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.box, .box3{
    width:146px;
    height:146px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box2, .box4{
    width:146px;
    height:289px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Someone has bound to have thought of this before now... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

#### Update - [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Fxxzy/)

no loops yet.. so if there was to be more than 14 (more than one collage)..it'd fail! this uses `:first-child`, `:nth-child`  and jQuery's [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

---

<strike>I haven't got an answer as such as</strike> I 'still' don't quite know how to create jQuery loops

but here's what my logic would be if that's any help..

`float:left;` **all** images in the CSS and let wrappers do the work

Outer **LOOP for each 14** img elements, then inside that loop

1. **create a grid**   = wrapper div @ 1152
   wide containing two divs @ 576 wide (floated side by side), with each if them containing an "inner" div @ 144 wide - like this - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/BFCWz/)

   all 14 images can be floated into this grid without any further "gridding" if you like
2. within this "14" loop create some more

   - **for first 8** images, size them to 72x72 and alternately place them in (append them to)  `.left .inner` and `.right .inner` so that each `.inner` div lands with 4 small images (they're floating left already so they will go into your positions)
   - **for next two** images size them 144*144
     and alternately append them to `.left .inner`
     and `.right .inner` 1 for each, they
     will float below the 4 that's already
     there completing the inner divs
   - **for next two** images size to 144*288
     and append them alternately to `.left`
     and `.right` this time.. they will float into the
     space beside the completed inner
   - **for next two** images size
     288*288 and like above append to `.left` and
     `.right` again they will float into the space
     that's left in each div

That completes the 14 loop which I suppose can just be repeated? I'm still learning, if the images aren't right now you could manipulate them with CSS

From here you should have enough hooks to be able to swap float directions via the CSS
you might need to change widths slightly for padding and whatnot (I included some in the updated demo), but I just tried to get the logic.

not sure if `nth:child` is the best option here, it's possible though, I did try it but because it needs loops it got to be just a set of overrides so I think some cleverer than me may be able to help more..

PS: I suggested the alternate placing for each loop of appending images as I think that's possibly easier to do than keeping counting.. but I could be wrong.. e.g. with the eight image it would make no difference if you append the first 4 to one and the next 4 to another rather the "*one to you, one to me*" approach

Great Question though, on my favourites as I would like to know the answer too :)

Comment: i commend you for your great effort even if you didn't totally know of the answer :)

Comment: @corroded, Thanks! it's probably way off.. but I learn by doing :)   - and of course I'd still like to know if there's a better or "more correct" way

Comment: This is excellent, I'm really impressed... I just now need to apply your logic to every 14 images, I think I'm looking at 7n+1 sort of equation or something.. my only edit to your logic so far is the styling if .right .inner {float: right;} was .right .inner {float: left;} then the .inner would be after the first "Big image" which is where I want it.. Thanks so much, I'll keep fiddling